# Identity Manager How To Get All Users Who Have Any Role

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

In my application, I have users who have role/roles saved at `AspNetUserRoles` and users who have no roles at all. I am trying to get all users "who have any role". So, I am trying to get all records saved at `AspNetUserRoles` table but I couldn't find any method to do that. Also, I don't want to fetch all Users then check them if they have any role assigned to them because it would cause performance loss. (Only 1% of all users have a role.) So, is there any method for it? I am using .Net Core 2.0.
Code Below:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace GebzeShared.Modules.GUI.Admin.Workflow
{
    public class MyClassWorkflow : IMyClassContract
    {
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
        private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;

        public MyClassWorkflow(
            UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
            RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager
            )
        {
            this._userManager = userManager;
            this._roleManager = roleManager;
        }

        public dynamic GetUserRoleList(ClaimsPrincipal user)
        {
            try
            {
                var currentUser = this._userManager.FindByEmailAsync(user.Identity.Name).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                var user2 = this._personnelRepository.Table.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Email == user.Identity.Name);
                var userRoleList = this._userManager.Users.Where(x => this._userManager.IsInRoleAsync(currentUser, "anyrole")); //dont want to use this
                {
                    RoleName = role.Name
                }).ToList<dynamic>();

                return new
                {
                    RoleList = roleList,
                };
            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                return "Error";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of querying the `UserManager` just query the set of roles on your `User` object.

`userManager.Users.Where(u => u.Roles.Any(r => r.RoleName == "anyrole"));`

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this (you need to inject `userManger` and `roleManager`):

```
List<ApplicationUser> usersInRole = new List<ApplicationUser>();
foreach (var role in roleManager.Roles)
{
    usersInRole.AddRange(await userManager.GetUsersInRoleAsync(role.Name));
}
```